# htaccess skip part of the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have a long URL like this http://example.com/interview/folder1/folder2/xxx. I need that page to be opened also in the short form like this http://example.com/interview/xxx.
I have tried this, it didn't help

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^interview/folder1/folder2/
    RewriteRule (.*) interview/$1
```

Please note that this is an excerpt from the htaccess which is much larger.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: htaccess is located in the root folder of the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^interview/folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule ^interview/(.*)$ /interview/folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I guess maybe it is because of other rewrites in my htaccess file. The project is in Magento, and the htaccess has a line like this
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
I tried the rewrite you suggested both before and after that line.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that your base url was in `interview` folder. Please see my edit and try placing this code before Magento internal Dispatcher `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`.

Comment: Still didn't work. I tried it without `[L]` on the last line of your code because otherwise the whole website crashes.